# How do I hide an entire row in a gird?

Tags: acumatica

Is there a way to hide an entire row, not just a single column, in a grid? I'm tried PXUIField.SetVisible, PXUIField.SetVisibility, PXUISetVisible, and PXUISetVisibility, but none of them seem to work. I know that using PXUIField.SetEnabled(cache, row, false) disabled the entire row, but can I make an entire row invisible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure the row is not returned in the query (could override the view delegate and not return specific rows) or removed from the cache. I don't think there is anything that can hide a row using the UI related calls, but I have never come across the need for this to ever try it.

Comment: I was afraid of that. It's what I figured, but I thought I'd still ask.

Answer (score 0):

The usual pattern is to use a PXFilter DataView current DAC record to filter the PXSelect DataView bound to the grid.

The filter fields are often changed on screen directly by the user but you can also set the value of the current filter DAC record programmatically in event handlers to build more complex logic.

```
public PXFilter<DACFilter> Filter;

public PXSelect<DAC,
       Where<DACFilter.field, Equal<Current<DACFilter.fieldFilter>>>> GridDataView;
```

Comment: Yes I understand that, but I wanted to hide a field that was already selected. I think I have a way around this, so it's alright, but if there is a way to hide a full row programatically outside of view filters, I'd still like to know.

Comment: You have to filter the DataSet, you can't manipulate it directly in BLC. As Brendan mentioned you can also filter the DataSet using view delegate.